# Object reference not set to an instance of an object date/time

Tags: c#, winforms

Why did i keep getting this error? "***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***"

Here is the code and where is the error pointing at:

```
namespace Sell_System
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
private TextBox dateContainer;
        private TextBox timeContainer;
private Timer timer;

 public Form4()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dateContainer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    timeContainer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.StartTimer);
    timer.Interval = 60000;
    timer.Start();
}
```

The reason why i put it into public Form4() was because i want time always updating every 60 seconds and when the time is reached 00:00AM, the date will increased by one day.

The error pointed at dateContainer.Text and when i comment that command, the error will be pointed at timeContainer.Text and so on until timer.Start();

Comment: Are these control instances initialized in the InitializeComponent call?

Comment: these instance are initialized right after the `public partial class (Your form name) : (Form)`

Comment: Probably the error is in `InitializeComponent()`. If possible, post that code too. Also, clarify wich version of c# you are using.

Comment: Do the name of class Fomr4 is same to designer class in which these controls are defined.

Comment: Simply put a breakpoint on the first line after the InitializeComponent. Run your code and when it hits the breakpoint tell us if the `dateContainer` is null or not. If it is null then you haven't still initialized it

Comment: yes, the dateContainer itself is null. But the DateTime.Now was displaying current time. What should i do then? I already initialized it, but not in the InitializedComponent();
See the code above, i already modified it.

Comment: No you haven't initialized them, you have only declared them

Comment: Is the 'Timer' a component that is beind created by the designer?

Comment: i am sorry, i was wrong. But, how do i initialized those in the InitializedComponent()? i am new at this matter. Please give me a solution at least. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The work of declaring and initializing controls on a winform application is done  when you put your controls on the surface of your form. In that way the WinForm designer add the appropriate code to the InitializeComponent and you could use your controls in your code.

If you add your control manually, as you have done, then it is your responsability to initialize then, define some of their basic properties and add these controls to the form control collection.

Something like this

```
namespace Sell_System
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
       // Declaration of your controls....
       private TextBox dateContainer;
       private TextBox timeContainer;
       private Timer timer;

       public Form4()
       {
          // This is were the controls defined by the form designer will be initialized
          // using all the default values for their property
          InitializeComponent();

          // Now you do it manually for the controls added manually
          dateContainer = new TextBox();
          // At least define the position where the control should appear on the form surface
          dateContainer.Location = new Point(10, 10);
          dateContainer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

          timeContainer = new TextBox();
          timeContainer.Location = new Point(30, 10);
          timeContainer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

          // To be shown the controls should be added to the Form controls collection    
          this.Controls.Add(dateContainer);
          this.Controls.Add(nameContainer);

          // The WinForm timer is just a component so it is enough to Initialize it
          timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();             
          timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.StartTimer);
          timer.Interval = 60000;
          timer.Start();
      }
}
```

Creating controls in this way could become messy very fast if you have to define many properties of the controls. So,if not really needed by a dynamic requirement, a manual creation of the controls  is not really a good practice.

Comment: Oh, okay. I just realized that i initialized them in the `Form_Load`, not in the `Form4` after `InitializeComponent`, that's why the program doesn't recognized them. haha.

Thanks by the way Mr Steve :D

And if you don't mind, i would like to ask a question. Is there any way to make a time in the program exactly same with the same in System (windows)? So, it is like when i run the program at (6:50:25 PM) <- System (windows time), the time at the program counting start at (6:50:25 PM) not at the (6:50:00 PM).

Comment: Oh well,  I have seen your comment only now. Probably you have resolved by yourself, but just change `DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`;

Answer (score 0):

When you make a class instance like

```
private TextBox dateContainer;
```

It will be null until some part of the program assigns a value to it. You need to write `dateContainer = ...` in the instructor or the init function.